# "FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed" - but the token is correct and it only happens on Chrome

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-authentication

Sending token from web-client to back-end via cookie (CROS issues with socketIO, cookies are the working solutions).
Works great on first call (authenticate). I test what happens on page refresh and it got the error.

The full error is:

> FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token
>
> code: 'auth/argument-error',

However:

- Copy/paste in notepad with the one from cookie and it is identical.
- More than that, after refresh it works like charm. It only happens on
- Chrome and not on FF.

**Note**: this is not about Android, I do get the right token, so it's not similar with the other question on stack.

Not sure if posting more code is useful as the error is not happening all the time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the cookie parser on server-side. Used a better library and now it works like magic. Case closed.